# How to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum came up when I was trying to evaluate $\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{11}\cdots$

I rewrote the sum as, $S = 9 \ \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n} \frac{1}{10^i-1}$

Wolfram gives an answer in terms of the digamma function.

Comment: Do you want to have the sum starting at 1? the way you wrote it the first term would be $\frac{1}{x^{0}-1}=\frac{1}{0}$

Comment: One can write this directly as a power series in $x$, the coefficient of $x^n$ being the number of divisors of $n$. Is this the kind of answer you are looking for?

Comment: @fiftyeight Edited the question. Sorry

Comment: You seem to have two equal terms in your original sum (two terms are $\frac1{11}$). Did you mean one of them to be $\frac1{111}$?

Comment: It is possible to express it as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}d\left(n\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}$ with $d$ giving the number of divisors of $n$. Similar to what Did said. If that's what your looking for I could write up an answer on it

Comment: That would help. Thanks @fiftyeight . I am trying that myself too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us apply the ratio test, so that the series converges if the following limit is less than 1 and diverges if it is greater than 1:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{1}{x^{n+1}-1}}{\frac{1}{x^{n}-1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^{n}-1}{x^{n+1}-1}\right|$$

For $\left|x\right|>1$
  this is:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1-\frac{1}{x^{n}}}{x-\frac{1}{x^{n}}}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|<1$$

For $\left|x\right|<1$ we can see the series diverges as the summand goes to $-1$.

So the series converges only when $\left|x\right|>1$
 . So when $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|<1$
 , and we can expand $\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}}$
  as a geometric series in that interval and it will converge.$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}}\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{n}}\left(1+x^{-n}+x^{-2n}+\dots\right)$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(x^{-n}+x^{-2n}+x^{-3n}+\dots\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}x^{-n\cdot m}=\sum_{\nu=1}^{\infty}d\left(\nu\right)\cdot x^{-\nu}$$

Here $d$ gives the number of divisors of $n$, including $1$ and $n$. The last equality is because for a given power $\nu$
  of $x^{-1}$
 , we will have a term for every pair $\left(n,m\right)$
  such that the product $n\cdot m$
  is $\nu$
 , and there is a pair like this for each $n$
  which divides $\nu$
 .