# Convergence and calculus of a sum $u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n}{u_n+b}$ with $b>1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've tried to resolve an undergraduate-level exercise and I can't conclude.

Let $u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n+a}{u_n+b}$ and $u_0 =1$ where $a,b\geq 0$.

We look for the numbers $a,b$ such that $\sum u_n$ converges.
I found that if $a>0$, $u_n \sim \frac{a}{b}$ and if it converges, $u_n \to 0$ so $a=0$.

When $a=0$ I found a good expression: $u_n=\frac{b-1}{b^{n+1}-1}$ so $\sum u_n$ converges if and only if $a=0$ and $b>1$.

Then the exercise says we can calculate the sum $\sum_{n\geq 1} u_n$ but I'm stuck here and tools like Wolfram don't help.

Thanks for any help or hint!

Comment: It remains to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{b^n-1}$ and there seems to be no nice formula, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403361/how-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1xn-1